# Truncating variable MATLAB

Tags: matlab, truncate

I'm working with an array `A` in MATLAB. The values in this array have up to 5 decimals. I would like to truncate those values to a less number of decimal.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually want to use less precision or just display it differently?

Comment: Just to summarize: if you *really* want to reduce precision for some reason, take a look at `fix`, `round`, `ceil`, `floor`. If you just want to display things more tersely, take a look at `format`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, Matlab's "truncate" function is called `fix`. So

```
>> fix(3.5) 
ans = 3

>> fix(-3.5)
ans = -3
```

To truncate, round, floor, or ceil anything to a given number of decimals, multiply by powers of tens, truncate, round, floor, or ceil, and then divide the result by powers of tens.

So:

```
>> fix(123.456 * 10^2)
ans = 12345

>> ans / 10^2
ans = 123.45
```

Comment: Curious why you use integer rounding with `fix`, and a work-around of multiplying and dividing, to achieve rounding? MATLAB has a perfectly good `round` function which rounds to a given number of digits...

Comment: The question was about truncating, not rounding. `fix(3.7)` and `round(3.7)` give different results. The reason I used multiplication and division is because `fix` does not take a precision argument, and neither do the other functions in older versions of Matlab.

Answer (score 4):

**Rounding Digits:**

To round a value (or matrix) to given number of decimal places, use `round`, for example to 2 decimal places...

```
round(1.2345, 2) 

ans = 1.2300
```

To also not display the trailing zeros, first change the format to `shortg`

```
format shortg

round(1.2345, 2)

ans = 1.23
```

The format `compact` can achieve similar results, choose the best one to suit your needs based on the documentation below.

**Documentation:**

Round: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html

Format: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html