# truncate decimal numbers in matlab?

Tags: matlab, rounding

Is there a quick and easy way to truncate a decimal number, say beyond 4 digits, in MATLAB?

`round()` isn't helping, it's still rounding off. I have to use it in for loop, so the quickest way is appreciated.

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Although this question has better answers, this is a possible duplicate of [Truncating variable MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549814/truncating-variable-matlab)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yet another option:

```
x = -3.141592653;
x_trun = x - rem(x,0.0001)

x_trun =

    -3.1415
```

Kudos to gnovice for the update.

In general, for `n` decimal places:

```
x_trun = x - rem(x,10^-n)
```

Comment: I considered this but it doesn't work for negative values.

Comment: Thanks, but my values are in negative

Comment: This should work for negative numbers if you change the `mod` to `rem`.

Comment: For clarity / flexibility, it might be easier to show this as `x - rem(x,10^-4)`, or `x - rem(x,10^-n)` where you're truncating at the nth decimal place

Comment: Thanks, easy and elegant

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks for the suggestion.  I updated the post.

Answer (score 11):

Here's one method to truncate `d` digits after the decimal.

```
val = 1.234567;
d = 4;
val_trunc = fix(val*10^d)/10^d
```

Result

```
val_trunc =

   1.2345
```

If you know that `val` is positive then `floor()` will work in place of `fix()`.

Comment: According to my benchmarks (see my answer), this is by far the quickest method, +1

Answer (score 6):

Truncating is like rounding if you subtract `5` from the decimal after the last you want to keep.

So, to truncate `x` to `n` decimal figures use

```
round(x - sign(x)*.5/10^n, n)
```

(Thanks to [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnovice) for noticing the need of `sign(x)` in order to deal with negative numbers.)

For example,

```
format long
x = 3.141592653589793;
for n = 2:5
    result = round(x - sign(x)*.5/10^n, n);
    disp(result)
end
```

gives

```
   3.140000000000000
   3.141000000000000
   3.141500000000000
   3.141590000000000
```

Comment: Thanks, but can we get rid of the zeros?

Comment: The zeros are purely dependant on your [`format`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) settings, not the rounding process. You will face the same output as the other methods here, but Luis likely had `format long` set.

Comment: @gnovice Thanks! Edited

Comment: @gnovice you couldn't have made that correction *before* I did a benchie? I bet `sign` is super cpu intensive ;)

Comment: @Wolfie It's all gnovice's fault! And nice benchie!

Answer (score 5):

As you asked for the fastest method, I've put together a quick benchmark of the top 3 truncation methods currently answered here. Please see the code below. I increased the size of the `x` vector to be rounded, using the `timeit` function for timing.

```
function benchie()
    % Set up iteration variables
    K = 17;  n = 4;  T = zeros(K,3);
    for k = 1:K
        x = rand(2^k,1);
        % Define the three truncation functions
        LuisRound = @() round(x - 0.5/10^n, n);
        JodagFix = @() fix(x*10^n)/10^n;
        InfoRem = @() x - rem(x,10^-n);
        % Time each function
        T(k,1) = timeit(LuisRound);
        T(k,2) = timeit(JodagFix);
        T(k,3) = timeit(InfoRem);
    end
    % Plot results
    figure
    plot(2.^(1:K), T); legend('LuisRound', 'JodagFix', 'InfoRem');
    grid on; xlabel('number of elements in x'); ylabel('time taken');
end
```

The resulting plot can be seen here:

[image: plot]

**According to this test, the `fix` method suggested by *jodag* is significantly quicker**, so you should use something like this for a custom truncation function to `n` decimal places:

```
function y = trunc(x, n)
%% Truncate matrix/scalar x to n decimal places
    if nargin < 2; n = 0; end; % default to standard fix behaviour if no n given
    y = fix(x*10^n)/10^n;      % return value truncated to n decimal places
end
```

tests:

```
>> trunc([pi, 10.45, 1.9], 4)
>> ans = [3.1415   10.4500    1.9000]
>> trunc([pi, 10.45, 1.9], 1)
>> ans = [3.1      10.4       1.9]
```

Comment: This test shows a limited view though.  If you  increase the number of elements from 131,072 (2^17) to 1,073,741,824 (2^30) you get a different picture.  And the `rem` option pulls ahead.  This is adjusting `x` in your code to `x = rand(2^k)-0.5;` to double the number of elements without increasing the number of iterations.

Comment: `rand(2^k)-0.5` as in a square matrix with values between -0.5 and 0.5? I didn't think having negative values would affect the result... currently away from my MATLAB PC so can't rerun the checks but might soon. **As always with benchmarks, mileage may vary**, this is why I provide the code so anyone can test with appropriate data for their purposes :)

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I really appreciate you including the code.  It's not until the big numbers that things change, which I find curious.  For example with 2^30 elements the elapsed time for *Rem* is ~67 s, for *Fix* is ~69 s, and for *Round* its ~203 s!  I may have to post a question now on why this would happen.

Comment: Do you have any visibility of the `round` function using `edit round` or is it obfuscated? It might be that there are extra checks, after all `fix` and `rem` are basically just subtraction, `round` has to check which way to send things

Comment: I was more wondering about how the performance of `rem` could improve over `fix` *after* a point.  It may have more to do with what else is going on, concurrently, in the operating system when dealing with that much memory at once.  (Can't check `round` right now.)

Answer (score -1):

Use my round2 function:

```
function result = round2(x,accuracy)
    if nargin<2, accuracy=1; end %default accuracy 1 same as 'round'
    if accuracy<=0, accuracy=1e-6; end
    result=round(x/accuracy)*accuracy;
end
```

Usual use: `round2(3.14159,0.01)` But you can also use it to round to every other multipler, for example: `round2(number,2)` will round to even number, or `round2(number,10)` etc..

Comment: This doesn't truncate, it rounds.